# Prevent FTP transfer from failing when FTP server is restarted

Tags: centos, fedora, selinux

When downloading large files (ca. 5GB) with the `lftp` client, I find that a restart of the FTP service (`vsftpd`) stops the transfer and I have to restart it from the beginning. Is there a way to prevent the transfer from failing when the FTP server is restarted?

Comment: Not restarting the FTP server isn't an option?

Comment: Expecting a restart of the FTP server not to kill the transfer is expecting too much; I'd suggest that the problem here is that the FTP server gets restarted too often, and that it'd be more worth your time to look for either a way to prevent that from happening, or an alternate file transfer mechanism that's more resilient than FTP. (For example, if the files are also available via HTTP from a service supporting the `Range` header, you can use a client such as `wget` which supports restarting partially completed downloads.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible as terminating the `vsftpd` service will also terminate any network connections it has.  Even if you could force the client to ignore this, the newly restarted service isn't going to know what to do with fragments of an FTP transfer in progress from a client that hasn't previously logged in to it.

FTP has a facility for resuming interrupted downloads, and `vsftpd` does support resuming if configured correctly.  [Looks like](http://murzal-arsya.blogspot.com/2009/12/multipart-sftp-download-and-resume.html) the `pget -c` option in `lftp` also supports resuming a client transfer.